# PHP similar multiple projects in one repository or one repository per project?

Tags: git, project

I have two very similar project but I don't know how they will be developed further. What are the best practices for a GIT repository for this type of project where many functionalities may be the same or similar ?

Comment: May be you could extract what is common about those projects and put it into a separate repository, creating a common dependency. It could be a shared framework, for example. After that, what is left in those two repositories might not seem that similar anymore.

Comment: I don't know what to do. It can just make separate repositories and possibly copy the same functionality between them.

Comment: Usually, you create a separate repository for each project, no matter how similar two projects are. Your concern should be code maintainability, and usually one addresses it by figuring out what is that same functionality shared by those projects and making sure you don't copy the same piece of code accross multiple projects, no matter how they are stored git-wise.

Comment: It may be that I will copy the same code to several projects because it will be largely the same. But there may be times when the same modules start to differ at some point as the projects evolve.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy them together in same folder you can use single repo

but I recommend using multiple repositories because it is more scalable.

If the shared code should be exactly same, you can use [git submodules](https://github.blog/2016-02-01-working-with-submodules/) which have it's own history and can be included in both repositories.

Comment: I think that you are probably right to create a separate repository for each project and copy common code between them.